# inquiry about represent the object name by the function parameter

Tags: javascript, styles

Things will be clear when you see the following example.

```
function AddStyle(prob, value) {
    Elem = document.getElementById('box');
    Elem.style.prob = value;
}

// Here is, when usage.
AddStyle('backgroundColor', 'red');
```

As you see in the previous example, we have two parameters (`prob` is the property Name), (`value` is the value of property).

That example doesn't work, There are no errors Occur also.
I'm certain that the problem in this line `Elem.style.prob = value;` and especially here `style.prob`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variables aren't resolved in that way.  Basically, you're code is looking for a property of style literally called `prob`.  You'll have to access the property using brackets, since objects are indexed by property name.  Something like:

```
Elem.style[prob] = value; // Access the property of style equal to the value of prob
```

This would be equivalent to:

```
Elem.style['backgroundColor'] = value;
```

Which would be equivalent to:

```
Elem.style.backgroundColor = value;
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/MUeEJ/)